Como poder conectar directamente una app kmp desktop con mysql
Se esta trabajando en una app multiplataforma, para esto se ha utilizado KMP(Kotlin Multiplatform), se tiene previsto lanzar la app en las tres versione, IOs, Android y Desktop, en el apartado de desktop, se tiene que conectar directamente a MySQL sin tener que utilizar un servicio externo, esto es por que la app desktop solo va a ejectuar en el "servidor" interno, esta app desktop tiene que utilizar ciertos sensores por lo cual una web no es viable, la duda que se tiene es:
Es posible conectar Kmp con MySQL directamente o si o si toca crear un servicio que lo permita?

Si ya existe el API para que Android e iOS se conecten, ¿por qué no usar la misma capa de servicios para la versión desktop?
